# too many initializers for array in struct

Tags: c++, c++11

I have:

```
struct X {
    int i, j;
};

struct XArray {
    X xs[3];
};

X xs1[3] { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };
XArray xs2 { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };
```

The `xs1` initializes fine, initializing `xs2` gives compiler error:

```
error: too many initializers for 'XArray'
 XArray xs2 { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };
                                     ^
```

What is wrong? Why can't I initialize?

Comment: How many members does an `XArray` have?

Comment: only xs (array) is the member.

Comment: Yet you are initializing it as if it had three members.

Comment: ah, got it, thanks

Comment: sorry, im naive in c++, all answers are correct, but cannot accept all :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need another level of curly-braces:

```
XArray xs2            { { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} } };
//                    ^ ^ ^
//                    | | |
// For XArray structure | |
//                      | |
//           For xs array |
//                        |
//      For the X structure
```

Answer (score 3):

The compileŕ assumes that *xs* is one field, the array will only be resolved when you add another brace like:

```
XArray xs2 { {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}} };
```

When you would add another element, e.g.

```
struct YArray {
    X a; 
    X xs[3];
 }
```

then it becomes clear that a and xs both need to be put into braces:

```
YArray y{ 
            {1,2}, // a 
            { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} } // xs 
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
X xs[3] = { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}};
```

Then you plug the whole part to the right into your code:

```
XArray x2 = { { {1,2}, ... {5,6} }};
```

This is because `XArray` has only one member, and it needs one pair of brackets enclosing it:

```
XArray t = { /* value */ };
```

And `value` happens to be an array, which also needs brackets:

```
X xs[3] = { /* value2 */ };
```

Since this array holds three values, each of them has to be initialized with a pair of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use:

```
XArray xs2 { { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} } };
```

This way the first element of `XArray` is initialized with: `{ {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} }`.

Online [here](http://ideone.com/lhMdOX)